# Intersection between a cylinder and a plane

Tags: surfaces, parametric, parametrization

I have to find the intersection between these two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$: this cylinder
$$x^{2}+y^{2}-8x-8y+28=0$$
and this plane:
$$x-y=0$$
and then find a parametric curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ of the intersection between them.

Well, from the plane, I got:
$$x=y$$
and in the cylinder, I got the parabola
$$2x^{2}-16x+28=0$$
My question is: how do I parametrize it? I tried something like:
$$\gamma(t)=(2t^{2}-16t+28,t,???)$$
But I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection is *not* a parabola. After simplifying you get

$$
x^2 - 8x + 14 = 0
$$

which can be written as

$$
(x - 4)^2 =  2
$$

and whose solutions are

$$
x = \pm \sqrt{2} + 4
$$

So the parametric form of the solution is just

$$
\gamma(t) = (\pm \sqrt{2} + 4, \pm \sqrt{2} + 4, t)
$$

I marked those in thick black lines in the figure below

[image]